# Left and right touches to invoke different methods - Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have been looking at how to invoke different touch methods depending on where the user touches on the screen. I presume this should be fairly simple in Sprite Kit but I can't find anything on it. Currently I am using the following to make the character jump.

How would I only use this method if it is touched on the left or the right of the screen? So a right touch calls one method and a left touch calls another. Thanks.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    if (isJumping == NO){

    isJumping = YES;
    SKSpriteNode* charNode = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"character"];
    [charNode runAction:jumpAnimation];
    [charNode runAction:jumpMovement];
    }

}
```

Comment: You can retrieve the `UITouch` in `touches` with `CGPoint pointLocation = [aUITouch locationInView:self.view];` You can use `CGRectContains` (if you want certains areas), or see if you `SKSpriteNode` is at left or right from the touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

    if(touchLocation.x < self.size.width/2)
        NSLog(@"left side");

    if(touchLocation.x > self.size.width/2)
        NSLog(@"right side");
}
```